# Expectation of product of two Vasicek distributed variables

Tags: expectation

It's shown in a research paper that:
$$
E\left[ \Phi\left(\frac{\Phi^{-1}(PD)-\sqrt{\rho_{1}}Y}{\sqrt{1-\rho_1}}\right) \times \Phi\left(\frac{\Phi^{-1}(LGD)-\sqrt{\rho_{2}}Z}{\sqrt{1-\rho_2}}\right)\right]= \Phi_2\left( \Phi^{-1}(PD), \Phi^{-1}(LGD); \rho\sqrt{\rho_1\rho_2}\right)
$$
where $Y$ and $Z$ are both standard normal distributed random variables and their correlation is $\rho$.

I was trying to derive this equation, but no success. Is there anyone could help? Thank you very much.

Comment: What is PD? What s LGD? What are $\Phi$ and  $\Phi_2$? What are $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$? That's a lot of whats ...  Moreover, the question contradicts itself:  it states:  `It's shown in a research paper that blah"` and then you ask for help to show the same result. If it is shown in the paper, why would you want to show it again. And which paper?

Comment: @wolfies sorry for the confusion. PD, LGD, $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$ are both constant, $\Phi$ is CDF of standard normal distribution and $\Phi_2$ is bivariant standard normal distribution. It is from a internal research paper, and in the paper it just gives out this equation without detailed derivation. Hope there extra information could help. Thanks.

Comment: If they are all constants, why do you need such clumsy and unnecessary notation?  $\Phi^{-1}(PD)$ is just a  constant $c_1$, $\Phi^{-1}(LGD)$ is just a constant $c_2$ etc.  Next, have you checked whether it actually holds for some numerical values?